# Task Scheduling : Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

**[I am following this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling)** to schedule a function every minute. Below is my code on localhost.

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call($this->WriteFile())->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }

    private function WriteFile() {
        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "John Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

I saw that the txt file is not showing the contents. i placed the txt file in public folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you added the the CRON entry to your server?

Comment: This is about localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my `Console Routes` in file `console.php` i have this command:

```
Artisan::command('writeFile', function () {
     Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'this is text !');
});
```

in my `Kernal.php` i have this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('writeFile')
             ->everyMinute();
}
```

also you need to run : `php artisan schedule:run`

file will be in path and the file will be in path : `"/storage/app/file.txt"`

you can read the file : `Storage::get('file.txt');`

worked just fine for me.. hope this will work with you :)

Comment: it should be like this : `Artisan::command('writeFile', function ($project) {
    Storage::disk('local')->put('newfile.txt', $txt);
});`


follow this link for [more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan)

Comment: you need add cron job to make `php artisan schedule:run ` runs every minute

Comment: you need to edit your `crontab` using command from cmd `crontab -e` then add this command `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
`

also you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp-XZm7INl8) for full example with registering run as cron job

Comment: no, you have to edit the `crontab ` in order to run the Laravel scheduler. 

using  `->cron('* * * * *')` is just translating `everyMinute` to cron language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979537/cron-job-is-running-two-different-commands-laravel-5